# Using LEFT JOIN to get a count returns a zero count when no data in main table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to get a count of apps for a user, using LEFT JOIN. It needs to return users regardless of whether they have apps, but the query is returning an empty record with 0 apps when no users are present.

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(a.id) AS apps_working  
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN apps a ON (u.id = a.user_id)
WHERE u.company_id = :company_id 
AND u.account_type = 3
```

EDIT: When there are no users present, the results look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [company_id] => 
        [user_login] => 
        [user_password] => 
        [first_name] => 
        [last_name] => 
        [user_hash] => 
        [user_slug] => 
        [date_joined] => 
        [last_login] => 
        [account_type] => 
        [status] => 
        [apps_working] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: When no users are present? How would it return users if there are no users in the results? What happens when you run without the join but the same WHERE conditions `SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_id = :company_id and account_type = 3;`. Do you get users back?

Comment: It is not returning any users, but an empty record with 0 apps. If I remove the join, the query is empty.

Comment: So, the query is empty because of your WHERE statement. You have no users in your user table that have a company_id equal to whatever you are loading into that parameter that also have an account_type of `3`

Comment: @JNevill Yes. That seems to be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a query that is ALWAYS going to return a value because count(*) will always return something.  If you don't want to see that, add a case statement to trap 0 and return null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(IFNULL(a.id,0)) AS apps_working  
    FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN apps a ON (u.id = a.user_id)
    WHERE u.company_id = :company_id 
    AND u.account_type = 3
```

Comment: This is still returning an empty record, with 0 apps. Meaning there are no users available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a left join query. So if there is no user satisfies conditions of company_id and account_type, there is no thing for joining and there is no thing in result.

Comment: Yes, the question is how to suppress the Count from returning 0 in the case of no results.